# Regular Expression AND NOT condition

Tags: regex

I am trying to filter images(.gif,.jpg) except of ico.gif from logs. 
my logs:

```
111.gif
aaa.jpg
abc.htm
ico.gif
222.gif
```

With regex, I would like to catch records as below:

```
111.gif
aaa.jpg
222.gif
```

Comment: Negating regexes usually results in very ugly expressions and can be less efficient as well. Can't you run two separate filters?

Comment: No, it has to be a single line in the configuration file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?:(?!\bico\b).)*\.(?:gif|jpg)$
```

Try this. This should do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
/^(?!.*\.ico\.gif$).*?\.(?:gif|jpg)$/gmi
```

working example:

http://regex101.com/r/rB0vW5/1

Comment: Thank you for your hins. Just change it a little. ^(?!.*ico\.gif$).*?\.(?:gif|jpg)$